# String representation of django-cms models/plugins

Tags: python, django-cms

I've built a [custom plugin](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/custom_plugins.html) for a [Django CMS](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/index.html) project which I've named `PageBlockPlugin`. The associated `PageBlock` model features an HTML field, and I've defined a `__str__` method on the model which truncates the HTML content to the first three words. When I'm in the Django admin view for this model, I see a list of instances which I've placed in one of my templates:

[image: Page Block Admin View]

This looks great! However, when I'm in the frontend editor for the same template and switch to "structure" view, what I see is just a list of instance ids:

[image: Page Block Frontend]

I've looked at a number of plugin examples and haven't been able to figure out how to use a model's string representation for it's associated plugin. Any ideas?

Here's a stripped-down version what I've defined so far:

**models.py**

```
class PageBlock(CMSPlugin):
    content = HTMLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return Truncator(strip_tags(self.content)).words(3, truncate="...")
```

**cms_plugins.py**

```
class PageBlockPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = models.PageBlock
    name = "Page Block"
    render_template = "some_template.html"

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context["instance"] = instance
        return context

plugin_pool.register_plugin(PageBlockPlugin)
```

**admin.py**

```
class PageBlockAdmin(FrontendEditableAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(models.PageBlock, PageBlockAdmin)
```

Comment: Which versions of Python, Django and Django-CMS are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7, Django 1.7, and Django CMS 3.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Python 2.7, you should use the `__unicode__(self)` method instead of `__str__(self)`. If you want to use the latter, you can use the `@python_2_unicode_compatible` decorator. Read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods).